# Change hover colour of FontAwesome span icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have this span:

```
<span class="fa fa-green fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

I changed the colour like this:

```
.fa-green {
    color: #008d4c;
}
```

However, the hover function does not work:

```
.fa-green:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what version of fontawsome? can you share a full code

Comment: and which set: svg or font based?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of span? It works for me.. <span class="fa fa-green fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true">Hello World!</span>

Comment: Does it work for you without the value?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsbin.com/xisecib/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis how you gonna see the color of nothing when you hover it or not? You need something to apply the color. If you want to change the background color on hover then you will need height and width.. https://jsfiddle.net/j4wo5xeq/1/

Comment: add a fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Make sure your **hover** style is not overridden by other styles or class.

html

```
<a href="#">
  <span class="fa fa-green fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></span
</a>
<a href="#" class="more-power">
   <span class="fa fa-green fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></span
</a>
```

css

```
    .fa-green {
      color: #008d4c
    }

    .fa-green:hover {
      color: black
    }

    a.more-power:hover span {
      color: #008d4c
    }
```

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ayjwm23d/36/